# android: is it possible to use in app purchases to store a real money balance for a user using the in-app billing API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm making an app that requires a user to store a small amount of money as an account balance that can be deducted from as needed in the app. I also want the user to be able to at any time be able to refund/withdraw their current balance back to their google play account. Is this possible to implement with the google play in-app billing API?

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: thanks, looks like I'll have to go a different route